# How to show a message box before star an activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, alert, message

In my activity i throw a new one with this code:

```
    intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

How to show a message before launching new activity? I would like to show a warning to users before going to new activity, in which just press OK button to go on...

Comment: see this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create a dialog.

```
Dialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
               .setMessage(R.string.dialog_fire_missiles)
               .setPositiveButton(R.string.fire, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
                       startActivity(intent);
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // User cancelled the dialog
                   }
               }).create();

dialog.show();
```

Comment: I get this error: The constructor Intent(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}, Class<NewActivity>) is undefined

Comment: It works if i use `Intent intent2` instead of `intent`. Otherwise i get this error: Multiple markers at this line
 - Cannot refer to a non-final variable intent inside an inner class defined in a different 
  method
 - The final local variable intent cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type
Any idea?

Comment: You just need to create a new Intent. I edited the code again.

Answer (score 1):

Just Copy this code:-  It will show only ok Button

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewActivity.class);
 builder.setMessage("Your Message");
 builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
  // User clicked OK button
 intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
       }
   });

 AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
```

Comment: I get this error: The constructor Intent(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}, Class<NewActivity>) is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Just use a dialog fragment and when the user clicks "Ok" , launch the activity then.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Answer (score 0):

you do it by using toast see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

for alert dialogue you can do [this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-alert-dialog-example/)

hope it helps.